# Why does operator==(std::variant<T, U>, T) not work?

Tags: c++, variant

Consider the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

int main ()
{
    std::variant<int, float> foo = 3;
    if(foo == 3)
    {
        std::cout << "Equals 3\n";
    }
}
```

[Godbolt demo here](https://godbolt.org/z/16Ta35W6a)

This does not compile because of the `foo == 3`:

```
<source>:7:12: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::variant<int, float>' and 'int')
    7 |     if(foo == 3)
      |        ~~~ ^~ ~
      |        |      |
      |        |      int
      |        std::variant<int, float>
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.1.0/include/c++/12.1.0/iosfwd:40,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.1.0/include/c++/12.1.0/ios:38,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.1.0/include/c++/12.1.0/ostream:38,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.1.0/include/c++/12.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.1.0/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/postypes.h:192:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _StateT> bool std::operator==(const fpos<_StateT>&, const fpos<_StateT>&)'
  192 |     operator==(const fpos<_StateT>& __lhs, const fpos<_StateT>& __rhs)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
// Many, many more rejected operator== candidates omitted
```

There's a free function [operator==](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/operator_cmp) that compares two `std::variant<int, float>`s. And there's an implicit conversion from `int` to `std::variant<int, float>`; that's how I was able to initialize `foo` in the first place. So why doesn't this comparison compile?

Strictly speaking, I suppose there are a few related questions here. One is why this doesn't *already* work, explaining how the rules for overload resolution apply to this section. And second is if there's anything that can be done in user-written code to make this comparison work sensibly.

Comment: I suppose one possibility is that if `T` appears more than once among the types of the left hand side, there's no sensible way to know which occurrence you want to check against, and consistency would discourage you from adding this kind of `operator==` for some, but not all, variants.

Comment: Overload (4) is implicit.

Comment: yes but the comparison operators still require variants of the same _type_ and `std::variant<int>` is not the same _type_ as `std::variant<int, float>` so it's not comparable. Moreover the implicit constructor does not have multiple type arguments so those would still need to be specified somewhere. Thus it exists only to support assignment construction as you're doing yourself.

Comment: I don't expect that `std::variant<int>` would get involved at any point. There's a perfectly good implicit conversion from `int` to `std::variant<int, float>`.

Comment: Except there isn't, the compiler can't magically assume that. It needs to have two types that are equivalent and there is no conversion from `int` to `std::variant<int, float>` so it assumes you the developer made a mistake and gives up.

Comment: Why isn't there an `operator <=>(const std::variant<..., T, ...>&, const std::variant<..., T, ...>&)`? Should be easy to define recursively or via `std::get<int>`.

Comment: @Mgetz There absolutely is such a conversion. It's overload (4) on the page of `std::variant` constructors. It's used in the calling code in my question.

Comment: You could use `if(foo == decltype(foo){3})` to be sure that you don't `std::get<int>` from a variant not carrying an `int`

Comment: @NathanPierson that's an assignment construction. Even if that was appropriate it would create `std::variant<int>` and not `std::variant<int, float>` as I stated above. Which is not comparable

Comment: Your issue is that the comparison functions are templates, and since `3` is not a `std::variant`, it can't deduce the template paramters.

Comment: A little helper goo: `bool operator==(std::variant<int, float> a, int b) { return std::get<int>(a) == b; }` ... and good to go.

Comment: @TedLyngmo In my actual code base there's a `using` shorthand for the full variant under consideration, so that's certainly one possibility.

Comment: @Eljay That looks like a reasonable implementation. Are there any potential pitfalls where, say, if I put that `operator==` definition in a namespace somewhere, the overload set would be generated using the `operator==` from namespace `std` before it found that?

Comment: The regular ADL rules apply.  If you really want to squirrel it away, but be accessible `namespace nathan { namespace common { ... }}` then you can `using namespace nathan::common;` in the translation units where you want it accessible.  If you were using your own user-defined type in your own namespace, then ADL would work to your advantage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither parameter of that `operator==` overload is an undeduced context. So template argument deduction for the overload will fail if it fails in either parameter/argument pair.

Since `int` is not a `std::variant`, deduction will fail for the corresponding parameter/argument pair and so the template overload is not viable.

Implicit conversions are not considered when deducing template arguments. Types must (with few minor exceptions) match exactly.